# Eventlistener for an alert of a webpage

Tags: java, selenium, event-listener

I need to know if a specific alert comes up on a webpage. I use an infinite loop inside a swingworker, something like this:

```
   try{
        WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#alert > a"));
        String gifAlert = container.getCssValue("background-image");
        if(gifAlert.equals(alert){
           //Do something
        }
   }catch(//Stuff){
      //Stuff
   }
```

is it possible to use an eventlistener that get continously the WebElement container and check continously if it matches alert instead of using a swingworker and that code inside an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know well Selenium but googling around [is possible to find the info that you may need](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/webdriver-event-listeners/)

However the general strategy is not to attach a listener to an element as much filter the element once an event is intercepted. So the two steps are implementing the listener

```
public class EventCapture implements WebDriverEventListener{

 @Override
 public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 // other overriding
}
```

then register it with the driver

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 EventFiringWebDriver eventHandler = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver); 
 EventCapture eCapture = new EventCapture(); 
 //Registering with EventFiringWebDriver
                //Register method allows to register our implementation of WebDriverEventListner to listen to the WebDriver events
 eventHandler.register(eCapture);
```